# Could not find or load the main class

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I m trying to run a project from command prompt but i get "could not find or load the main class". Firstly i compile the classes of the project which are located in src folder.

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\toc\ENTRIES-champ\entry\src
  set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin
javac -d ../classes champ2009client/*.java

The above commands create the class files of the project. After that i try the above commands to run main class:

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\toc\ENTRIES-champ\entry\classes
java champ2009client.Client champ2009client.driver

pause

where classes\champ2009client folder is where the class file is located. In my laptop which have Win xp32 it works fine but in my pc i got could not find or load main class error. Is there possibility to got problems from windows 7??

Comment: Check the versions of the `Java` you are using, might be they are different, for if the compilation has been done by the higher version, you have to recompile it for the lower version. Check it by writing `javac -version` on the command prompt of both the computer.

Comment: Are you sure your .class files aren't in `src/`?

Comment: i use the command set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin in the beggining of the file. I think with that command compling and running is with the same version.

Comment: Class files is in classes folder for sure. Before compiling the class i erased them so as not to have complications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run your your program as below

> java -classpath . your_class_that_has_main_method

Comment: You mean sth like that ->
java-C:\Program Files (x86)\toc\ENTRIES-champ\entry\classes\ champ2009client.Client